# How to bold text in xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file and an xsl stylesheet, how do I bold all the books with the style attribute of coding?

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>

<catalog>
<book sytle="coding">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</book>
<book style="fantasy">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <price>7.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
```

```
<book style="fantasy">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
  <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
</book>
 <book style="fantasy">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <price>12.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
 </book>
 <book sytle="coding">
<author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
<title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
<price>36.95</price>
<publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
<description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
</book>
<book sytle="coding">
<author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
<title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
<price>16.95</price>
<publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
<description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
SAX and more.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

How do I bold all the books with the attribute coding?
And display the books that are less than 10.00?
Using xslt

Here is the xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <style>
            body {background-color:#DACFE5; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
            book.coding {color:#0D3427}
        </style>
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="0">
                <tr bgcolor="#1171ba">
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/book">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="title">
    Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
    <xsl:value-of select="book/@style = 'coding'"/></span>
    <br />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XML doesn't have bold text, but HTML does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `xslt` you need. Note that you have a misspelling in the `style` (`sytle`) attribute in your `xml`.

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <style>
                body {background-color:#DACFE5; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
                .coding {color:#0D3427;font-weight:bold;}
            </style>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr bgcolor="#1171ba">
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/book[price &lt; 10]">
                        <xsl:element name="tr">
                            <xsl:if test="@sytle='coding'">
                                <xsl:attribute name="class">coding</xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                        
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                        
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```